# $c_2$ of Calabi-Yau three-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $Y$ be a smooth compact Calabi-Yau three-fold (over $\mathbb C$, with $\pi_1(Y)=0$). Is it true that $c_2(Y)$ is Poincare dual to an effective curve? If not, can one construct a counter-example?

Note, that the answer to the same question for Fano $3$-folds is positive, as is stated here: [Do all Fano threefolds have effective $c_2$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297248/do-all-fano-threefolds-have-effective-c-2) However, I don't understand if that answer applies to Calabi Yaus too.

Comment: Some remark: it is possible to have $c_2(Y)=0$ even for $Y$ Calabi-Yau in a strict sense ($K_Y$ trivial and $H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)=0$): take a $Y$ of the form quotient of an abelian 3-fold by a finite group.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I consider trivial as effective. I imagine such an example has infinite $\pi_1$?